# Linq Join with Dynamic Expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-expressions

I'm attempting to do a dynamic join in linq. Meaning that I only know at runtime what field the join will occur on.

I've done the following:

```
var itemParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(E), "obj");
var entityAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression.Parameter(typeof(E), "obj"), typeof(E).GetMember(Field).First());
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(entityAccess, itemParam);
var q = dbSet.Join(context.Acl, lambda, acl => acl.ObjectID, (entity, acl) => new { Entity = entity, ACL = acl });
```

However this throws at compile time, even though lambda appears to be the right syntax telling me that  it cannot convert from LambdaExpression to `Expression<System.Func<E, int>>`.

How do I get it to create the right expression dynamically that uses my field (i.e. property "Field" above in the `typeof(E).GetMember(Field).First())` line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Expression.Lambda<TDelegate>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336566%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so that you end up with the line

```
// obj => obj.Field
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<E, int>>(entityAccess, itemParam);
```

**Update**

As per your comment, the reason the expression fails is because you are using two different parameters. You define `itemParam`, but then do not use it in `Expression.MakeMemberAccess`

Try the following instead:

```
// obj
var itemParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(E), "obj");

// obj.Field
var entityAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(itemParam, typeof(E).GetMember(Field).First());
```

Comment: That compiles but then I get: The parameter 'obj' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at my update, you need to use the same instance resulting from `Expression.Parameter`

Comment: No problem, I find writing the equivalant C# in a comment helps to keep track of what is going on.